# Como faço para ordernar de forma decrecente um campo data no mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

Como faço para ordernar de forma decrescente `(select * from tabela order by date desc)` um campo data inserido pelo datepicker script no formato **dd-mm-yyyy** no Mysql?

Obs: As datas estão sendo ordenadas apenas pelo dia, ignorando o mês e o ano que vem em seguida. E o campo data é do tipo varchar (10).

Ex: 02-05-2018 (dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: O que há de errado com o `select * from tabela order by date desc`?

Comment: as datas são ordenadas apenas pelo o dia, ignorando o mês e o ano que vem em seguida. Esqueci de mencionar que o campo data é do tipo varchar (10).

Comment: 02-05-2018 (nesse formato)

Comment: Compreendo. Seria ideial adicionar essas informações na pergunta, para isso basta clicar no botão [edit]

Comment: corrigido, grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por conta da data estar em `string` ele irá ordenar apelas pelos dados antes do **"-"**, é necessário converter o campo para `date`

```
select 
  *
from tabela
  order by str_to_date(data, '%d-%m-%Y') desc
```

Coloquei um exemplo no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1efdd8/10) para referencia.

Comment: Show, muito obrigado @Barbetta, era isso mesmo, agora como escrevo essa query para o codeigniter? rs

Comment: @Ramiro, o ideal é criar uma pergunta para cada dúvida, mas, no `codeigniter` você pode jogar a `query ` diretamente, [veja aqui na documentação](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html) caso essa resposta tenha ajudado, não se esqueça de marcar como resolvida, caso tenha solucionado seu problema [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079)

Comment: Ok, obrigado. Já marquei como resolvida, desculpa aí, sou  novato no site.

Comment: @Ramiro, imagina, não precisa pedir desculpas. estamos ai para se ajudar =D. Qualquer coisa, [faça um tour pelo SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)